# xamarin android player (emulator) wont start properly

Tags: android-emulator, xamarin.android, virtualbox

Xamarin android player (XAP) not able to boot emulators [see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjoM4.png) when i start the emulator i get an error message saying the emulator timed out continue to wait yes /no? if i select yes after a while the emulator starts , and the (emulator screen) keeps on flashing , thought it might be the version of the model ? but it also do it with nexus 4 /5 /7 ?? I tried renaming of the devices and factory reset using Xamarin Android Player.

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling Xamarin Android Player and also uninstall Oracle VM VirtualBox. Then, reinstall them. I had a similar problem caused by Oracle VM VirtualBox issue.

Also, according to this bolg post:
https://blog.xamarin.com/live-from-dotnetconf-cycle-7-xamarin-studio-6-and-more/

Xamarin Android Player is now deprecated and instead you can use the Visual Studio Emulators for Android.